# Issue connecting my lambda function to Amazon managed blockchain

Tags: aws-lambda, hyperledger-fabric, grpc, hyperledger, amazon-managed-blockchain

I am failing with a DNS 14 message when trying to call a lambda function to invoke chaincode on my Amazon Managed Hyperledger Blockchain.

```
ERROR   Failed proposal response. Status code: undefined. Message: 14 UNAVAILABLE: DNS resolution failed. Stack: Error: 14 UNAVAILABLE: DNS resolution failed
```

at Object.exports.createStatusError (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/grpc/src/common.js:91:15)
at Object.onReceiveStatus (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:1209:28)
at InterceptingListener._callNext (/opt/nodejs/node_modules/grpc/src/client_interceptors.js:568:42)

I believe that it is due to a grpc link used to access the peer node endpoint.

I've tried logging all of the request fields, but it is difficult to figure out which configuration is missing.

Answer (score 0):

Try to perform `nslookup` against the peer address. If it fails, see whether you have created VPC Endpoint for the Hyperledger Fabric network.